# Why my app.get('/') is not getting request in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to backend development and learning express. I have the following code:

`index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("hitting request");
})
app.listen(3001,()=>console.log("Mock server listening at 3001"));
```

But when I am hitting `http://localhost:3001/` in postman nothing is printed on console.

May anyone tell me why I am getting this issue? I am also using nodemon as dev dependency.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "mock-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bignumber.js": "^9.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error message in the terminal after running "npm run dev"?

Comment: Just to be sure. Is nothing printed on the postman console or on the nodejs console, e.g. the terminal you used to run `npm run dev`.

Comment: I would add at least `res.end()` or `res.send('hello')` at the end of the handler function so that the server can produce a response to the client.

Comment: Just to make sure: You actually did start your server? Right? Does postman show any error? Do you get any errors in the console where you started your server?

Comment: I just added allowed `allow-cross-origin:*` in cors and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You used

```
console.log("hitting request");
```

Means you will get the "hitting request" message on the console you used (CMD for example).
If you want to get it in postman you have to use :

```
res.send("hitting request");
```